# discord.py | Have the bot post a random image from a specified folder

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As mentioned above, I'm trying to make a command that sends a random image from a specified folder. I'm not tech-savvy, so I'd greatly apprechiate it. The folder it's supposed to take a picture from has around ~120 images, all with formats ranging from png to jpg and even bmp, so having an array is very inefficient and time-consuming.

Comment: Hi Dr. Glitchgo, can you share the work you've done so far, or post example code? This question is a bit vague for SO

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what makes a question too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-needs-more-focus-and-trying-to-understand-it). Is the problem uploading an image using discord.py, or choosing a random image from a folder? What do you have so far

Comment: @Kaia The problem is having it grab an image and uploading it

The code I have right now is this:

Comment: @client.command(brief="Get a random Natsuki image")                                   # Natsuki image from "Natsuki Worship"
async def img(ctx):
    try:
        natsu_channel = client.get_channel(773887728110010378)  # Channel id here
        natsu_pics = await natsu_channel.history(limit=500).flatten()
        natsu_pic = random.choice(natsu_pics)
        natsu_pic_url = natsu_pic.attachments[0].url
        await ctx.send(natsu_pic_url)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error: Please try again.")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it via this command:

`await ctx.send(file=discord.File("PATH\TO\IMAGES\\" + random.choice(os.listdir("PATH\TO\IMAGES"))))`